# Binary search on two monotonically increasing arrays?

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

Let's say we have two monotonically increasing arrays

```
x = 50, 78, 103, 117, 130, 137, 143, 146, 149, 151, 153, 154, 155  
y = 62, 93, 108, 116, 121, 125, 128, 130, 131, 132, 133
```

Each move of **x costs 1 coin** and **y costs 2 coins**.
We need to answer the **minimum cost** required using both arrays to make sum **K**.

```
m1*x + m2*y >= K
where m1 and m2 are number of moves.
```

For example **K=238** then,

- Minimum number of moves required from x is **5** i.e till 130 which costs **5 * 1 = 5 (cost of each move in x is 1)**.
- Minimum number of moves required from y is **3** i.e till 108 which costs **3 * 2 = 6 (cost of each move in y is 2)**.

This gives us total sum **238** and minimum cost **5 + 6 = 11**.

1. One approach is to use two pointers.
2. How can I use binary search to solve this kind of question?

Comment: What do you mean with **move**? What is the start position? _"How can I use binary search to solve this kind of question?"_ Instead of increasing and decreasing one pointer by one you can binary search for the difference. How is this question related to C++?

Comment: understand this with another example say k=238 we can also do this by choosing 117 from x and 121 from y, to reach 117 from starting position on array x we need 4 moves and to reach 121 from starting position on array y we need 5 moves, so total cost 4*1 + 5*2 = 14.

Comment: Ok thanks for clarification, removed c++ tag!

Comment: What is the starting position? As a rule of thumb: if you need an example to fully describe a problem you don't understand the problem.

Comment: So, by _move_ you mean how many tests it requires to find a certain number in the arrays? The starting position is somewhere outside the array and the first _move_ is making the pointer point at the first element in the array?

Comment: Yes, exactly the first move is making pointer point at first element and each ith move costs 1 coin in x and 2 coin in y.

Comment: Ok, then what is the problem with using binary search? For the example, searching for 130 in x would require 3 _moves_ (if I'm reading it correctly): 137, 103, 130

Comment: But that's not the move, move is counted as position of 130 from starting of the array (indexed from 1) which is 5.

Comment: Ah, ok, I think I understand.

Comment: As I understand it, *move* is maybe not the term you're after. You are looking to minimize a cost function that penalizes using array entries the more to the right they are in the array.